# How to make a custom embed code responsive using CSS

Tags: css

I need to embed a custom embed code from an external website into my wordpress blog post.

the custom embed code has this format:

```
<!-- TradingView Chart BEGIN -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://s3.tradingview.com/tv.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var tradingview_embed_options = {};
tradingview_embed_options.width = '640';
tradingview_embed_options.height = '400';
tradingview_embed_options.chart = 'z1zThvGU';
new TradingView.chart(tradingview_embed_options);
</script>
<p><a href="https://www.tradingview.com/chart/GBPUSD/z1zThvGU-GBPUSD-Forecast-on-H4/">GBPUSD, Forecast on H4.</a> by <a href="https://www.tradingview.com/u/DatTong/">DatTong</a> on <a href="https://www.tradingview.com/">TradingView.com</a></p>
<!-- TradingView Chart END -->
```

the code works fine but its not fully responsive when viewed in mobile or table and its not also centered in desktop. maybe because the code has generated a fixed width and a fixed height.

But that is the issue. I need to override the embed code styles so that I can style it however I want.

I have tried many options but its not working. I also inspected the DOM and found out that there is a wrapping div that was generated but when trying to style that generated wrapping div, its still not working. another option I did was to manually wrapped the code inside wordpress editor hoping that I can control the width and the height but still its not working. Although even if it worked, its not a good idea to manually style it in each and every blog posts so it would be great if we can overrride it using a custom stylesheet.

See fiddle below:

http://jsfiddle.net/7695akjh/8/

Any ideas how I can make this code fully responsive?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after fiddling with the markup, I finally figured it out! so this is solved.